# Beyond the call of duty

Tags: discussion

I thought it might be beneficial to collect some examples of questions when an answerer goes "beyond the call of duty" to deliver an excellent answer. I mean answers that are not only excellent, but where the answerer delivers a much better answer than anyone would expect for that question.

For example, consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python/2626364#2626364) in my question about the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` in Python. Note that the answer was added a long time after the activity on the question seemed to have stopped and it answered many questions that I didn't ask, but I wanted to know the answer to nonetheless.

So, any other examples?

Comment: Downvote drive-by, baby. :(

Comment: Looks like it should have been good for a Necromancer badge, anyway.  Silver badges are worth having for most people.

Comment: I should mention that I ignore any downvotes I receive without comments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to reward the guy, unaccept his answer, start a bounty for 500 rep, then accept his answer.

At least, I think that might work. It'd cost you 500 rep, though.

Comment: Nice idea! It will cost him only 500 rep, though. The 50 are chipped in by the system.

Comment: this is valid, and we support this, but be advised that you must wait 24 hours after starting a bounty before accepting.

Comment: 550 - lolz, that'd be half my rep. I added a 100 point bounty though